# GNU make VPATH not properly used to rewrite object paths in rules

Tags: makefile

my Makefile:

```
CC=cc
INC=-I.
CFLAGS=-g  -DDEBUG -std=gnu99 -DSFHASH -DDOMAIN
LDFLAGS=-ldl
OBJS=*.o
OBJDIR=.obj
BINDIR=.obj
LIBDIR=.obj

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) -DSFHASH -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<


VPATH = .obj
#vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)

hashtest: hashfuncs.o hast.o scanners.o parseargs.o
        $(CC) -rdynamic -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        @rm -f $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJS) $(BINDIR)/hashtest
```

using it for the first time: make does not rewrite gcc's input file paths:

```
@delphi# make clean
@delphi# make
cc -I. -g  -DDEBUG -std=gnu99 -DSFHASH -DDOMAIN -DSFHASH -o .obj/hashfuncs.o -c hashfuncs.c
cc -I. -g  -DDEBUG -std=gnu99 -DSFHASH -DDOMAIN -DSFHASH -o .obj/hast.o -c hast.c
cc -I. -g  -DDEBUG -std=gnu99 -DSFHASH -DDOMAIN -DSFHASH -o .obj/scanners.o -c scanners.c
cc -I. -g  -DDEBUG -std=gnu99 -DSFHASH -DDOMAIN -DSFHASH -o .obj/parseargs.o -c parseargs.c
cc -rdynamic -o .obj/hashtest hashfuncs.o hast.o scanners.o parseargs.o -ldl
cc: error: hashfuncs.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: hast.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: scanners.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: parseargs.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [hashtest] Error 1
```

using it second time in a row, it does:

```
@delphi# make
cc -rdynamic -o .obj/hashtest .obj/hashfuncs.o .obj/hast.o .obj/scanners.o .obj/parseargs.o -ldl
@delphi#
```

GNU Make manual says:

> The value of the make variable VPATH specifies a list of directories
>   that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to
>   contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory;
>   however, **make uses VPATH as a search list for both prerequisites and**
>   **targets of rules**.

I would understand if VPATH is a set-once-at-startup-typeof-variable but it's not. The fact that the target's dependencies generated at runtime are properly looked up says so.

What's up with that? Why is make correctly rewriting input file paths for gcc only the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of this behavior can be found in [section 3.7 of the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles):

> 3.7 How make Reads a Makefile
>
> GNU make does its work in two distinct phases. During the first phase it reads all the makefiles,
>   included makefiles, etc. and internalizes all the variables and their values, implicit and
>   explicit rules, and constructs a dependency graph of all the targets and their prerequisites.
>
> During the second phase, make uses these internal structures to determine what targets will
>   need to be rebuilt and to invoke the rules necessary to do so.

When you run the `make` for the first time, the prerequisites in the `.obj` directory do not yet exist. That means that they will not be part of the dependency graph as created during the first phase. Consequently, these prerequisites are not used during the second phase when executing the rule to create `hashtest` -- even though they exist by that time due to rules previously executed during the second phase.

When you run `make` for the second time, these prerequisites do exist and are found and included in the dependency graph by virtue of the `VPATH` setting.

Please note that the expression in `VPATH` is *only* a search path, nothing more. It can contain multiple directory names, separated by a colon. `make` will search in that search path for prerequisites and targets while constructing the dependency graph during the first phase. If it finds a particular target in a directory in that search list, then that target is added to the dependency graph as an existing file, that might or might not be out of date.

You seem to expect that `make` adds a subdirectory from `VPATH` to a target, even if that target does not exist in that subdirectory and needs to be created. That is not how it works -- how would `make` deal with multiple directories in `VPATH` in that case?

Comment: but still, the object files are properly looked up in .obj as dependencies for hashtest when I run make first time. if make does this, why does not also properly expand $^ ?

Comment: "properly expand $^" : including the VPATH prefix where make found the dependencies while resolving them

Comment: I do not see any file in `.obj` appear as dependency in your first run. The directory `.obj` only appears because you explicitly mention it via `$(OBJDIR)` and `$(BINDIR)`. During that run, the objectfiles are not "properly looked up in .obj", as you state it.

Comment: I added some extra explanation at the bottom of the answer; hope this helps.

Comment: you are correct. I fooled make with the rule of building object files. the target is %.o (resolving to current directory) but I am generating the files in .obj. but then I fooled myself. thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Subject: Re: (un)expected make behavior while using VPATH
From: mad scientist
```

> <<<     %.o: %.c
>
> <<<             $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) -DSFHASH -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<
>
> This is an invalid rule.  It violates one of my "rules of makefiles":
>
> http://make.mad-scientist.net/rules.html
>
> <<< using it for the first time: make does not rewrite gcc's input file paths:
>
> <<< using it second time in a row, it does:
>
> Classic.  Don't feel bad, that's what EVERYONE does at first.  That
>   may well point out that VPATH is mis-designed (or that some other
>   facility is needed).  However, that's another conversation.  This
>   might help:
>
> http://make.mad-scientist.net/vpath.html
>
> Cheers!

from help-make ml, thread http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2012-11/msg00018.html